# how to insert a SAML Assertion to SOAPHeader

Tags: xml, dom, saml, wss4j, assertion

NB-6.8 jdk-1.6.14 WSS4j-1.5.8 ,OpenSAML-2.3.0
I try to modify WSS4J-1.5.8 to operate SAML 2.0, and I could not insert a generated assertion to existing SOAP Header, the code like this:

```
Assertion assertion = createAssertion("some subject", "some issuer");

    Document doc = docBuilder.parse("request.xml");

    Element parent = doc.getDocumentElement();

    Node node = parent.getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Header");
    node.appendChild(assertion.getDOM());
```

Error  : WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.

but in wss4j, some functions like insertSecurityHeader do so(appendChild or inserBefore) ,too. They do work, why it's wrong in my code? what I miss.

Comment: think its importNode() on the owner document you are looking for.

Comment: it no works. I do not see that any element is added to doc although it should be like javadoc said.

Comment: I recently ran into a similar issue. In my case it was because of some missing namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the owner document of *assertion* is different from the owner document of *node*. To resolve this, the owner document of *node* has to take ownership of *assertion* before you can append it. 
As ralph pointed out you can use `node.getOwnerDocument().adoptNode(assertion)` to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ran into problems using importNode (NAMESPACE_ERR), which could be resolved using adoptNode instead.